# How to copy everything except data from one database to another?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, database-cloning

In T-SQL (Microsoft SQL 2008), how can I make a new database which will have the same schemas, tables, table columns, indexes, constraints, and foreign keys, but will not contain any data from the original database?

Note: making a full copy, then removing all data is not a solution in my case, since the database is quite big, and such full copy will spend too much time.

Comment: Can't you just export the database without the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for instructions: [How To Script Out The Whole Database In SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-to-script-out-the-whole-database-in--2008)

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear enough. I need this to run as a scheduled task or a maintenance plan, not just one time. Since database structure change frequently, I can't just script the whole database like this.

Comment: In that case use SMO and build your own solution in .NET and this then you can schedule. Also take a look into visual studio database projects(Visual Studio Team System for database architects in 2008 but I believe in 2010 Pro also has this) which could be used for this also

Comment: It seems you can do this programmatically as well
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.script.aspx

You might also look at using something like a .dbproj in VS to manage and keep version control over your schema changes.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Management Studio, right click on the database and select "Script database as"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078.aspx

You can then use the script to create an empty one.
Edit : OP did say 2008

Comment: 2008 doesn't have Enterprise Manager

Answer (score 0):

I use liquibase for this purpose. Just point liquibase to a different server and it will use your changelog to bring the second database up to date, schema wise. It has the added benefit that the changelog file gets stored in source control and so I can have tagged versions of it, allowing me to restore a database to what a specific version of my app is expecting.